# Using `shred` from the command line

Tags: macos, macports, secure-erase

I need to securely erase some files. I have used `shred` on linux systems before, so I looked around and found that `shred` is part of the `coreutils` package in macports. I did `port install coreutils` to install coreutils, but I still can't find `shred` in the command line.

How can I get `shred` to work on my mac's command line? If it matters, I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)

Comment: Note the security of `shred` depends on the filesystem being used, I don't know how effective it is on HFS.

Comment: shred is not effective on journaled file systems that is why it is not available. SRM also was found to not be effective. Just delete normally and pray seems to be the only hope on hfs+ journaled filesystems

Comment: Really?! Could you please talk about why it is not effective?

Comment: Journaled filesystems record the changes that will be made before the write to the disk. It can be used to recover from file corruption, or recover data you wish had been shreded.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`port install coreutils` adds a g prefix to the names of binaries, so shred is `/opt/local/bin/gshred`.

Comment: `brew install coreutils` makes `gshred` available for those using Homebrew.

Answer (score 71):

OSX has a built in command `srm` to securely remove files. See https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/srm.1.html. You can also use `rm -P` to overwrite the files with sequences of bytes three times.

With sierra or later, macOS no longer includes srm. But users can install it with homebrew:

```
brew install homebrew/dupes/srm && brew link --force homebrew/dupes/srm
```

Comment: Sure, but shred lets me set the number of overwrites. These tools don't. Any ideas on how to get that functionality?

Comment: You can use the `-m` option for seven overwrites or `-s` for only one, but I don't think you can specify a specific number.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. I didn't know the `srm` command existed. It overwrites, renames and truncates the file before deleting it. That, plus the 7 US DoD compliant passes (0xF6, 0x00, 0xFF, random, 0x00, 0xFF, random) (-m option) guarantee the file is irrecoverable.

Comment: As of macOS Sierra, `srm` is no longer included.

Comment: macOS users can install `srm` with brew command `brew install homebrew/dupes/srm`.

Comment: `homebrew/dupes` is now deprecated.  [Seems](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/blob/master/tap_migrations.json) that `srm` was removed and not migrated to `homebrew-core`.

Comment: `srm` was moved from `homebrew-dupes` to `homebrew-core` then removed entirely. There's a 3rd party [tap for it here](https://github.com/khell/homebrew-srm); install with `brew install khell/homebrew-srm/srm` then `srm secrets.txt`, etc. 
Better to not though.. see this [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1208987/160743).

Comment: I have spindle, usb sticks, ssd, etc that I attach ... srm is a good tool for some of them.

Comment: Btw, `rm -P` the `man rm` tells: `-P      This flag has no effect.  It is kept only for backwards compatibility with
             4.4BSD-Lite2.` on MacOs Ventura 13.1

Answer (score 35):

@user495470's answer is correct for the question posed. The problem is neither `srm` or `shred` really make sense for modern systems.

This is mostly due to SSDs. Unlike magnetic disks, modern TRIM-enabled disks automatically clear deleted data in the background.

SSD's also perform wear leveling. This makes attempts to "over-write" a file both futile (you'll be writting to a different physical location) and undesirable (it needlessly contributes to disk wear).

All Macs that come with an SSDs have TRIM enabled.

The other problem the file system, specifically journaled file systems, which can keep a copy of data elsewhere before it's written out.

Even on magnetic media this can cause problems for both [`srm`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/srm/files):

> All users [..] should be aware that srm will only work on file systems that overwrite blocks in place. In particular, it will *NOT* work on [..] the vast majority of journaled file systems.

And [`shred`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#shred-invocation):

> [..] shred relies on a very important assumption: that the file system overwrites data in place. [..] many modern file system designs do not satisfy this assumption. Exceptions include: Log-structured or journaled file systems [..]

HFS Plus volumes are journaled by default since Mac OS X v10.3.

**These days, the best way to securely "deleted" files is to enable FileVault (so they're never write disk unencrypted in the first place) then just delete them and let TRIM sort it out.**

If, by stroke of misfortune, you're on a magnetic medium, have journalling disabled and, for some reason, can't encrypt the disk, you're options are:

- Use `rm -P` which overwrites files with `0xff`, then `0x00`, and then `0xff` again
- Install `coreutils` for `gshred` (ie. `brew install coreutils && gshred secrets.txt`)
- `srm` has been removed from `homebrew-dupes` and `homebrew-core` but [someone's](https://github.com/khell) [published a tap here](https://github.com/khell/homebrew-srm) that works (ie. `brew install khell/homebrew-srm/srm && srm secrets.txt`)
- [Physical destruction of the medium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-ckechIqW0) :)

Comment: But I guess shred is still fine if you shred the whole partition or the whole disk.

Comment: You mean like `shred /dev/hda`? Yeah, I guess so. The blocks being addressed by the OS are still abstracted from the physical memory though and are potentially being remapped _during_ the shred. I wonder if any wear leveling and reserve space is implementations could cause this to not always work..

Comment: +1 for the explanation about why shredding is pointless on SSDs and the suggestion to use FileVault. Is APFS journaled or do we know how it handles file deletion? (Should probably be a separate thread!)

Comment: There seems to be the assumption here that secure deleting is needed only for 'internal' drives. Attached drives come in all forms and srm would be appropriate for some of them.

Comment: On macOS Ventura, `rm -P`'s documentation says: This flag has no effect.  It is kept only for backwards compatibility with 4.4BSD-Lite2.