# Mac OS Sierra and srm

Tags: macos, rm

I had a script for securely emptying my trash bin from time to time and I was using `srm`. I suppose people would still have uses for `srm`. However, it appears that `srm` no longer ships with mac os. Are you aware of a candidate alternative to `srm`? Any word by anyone at all?

P.S. For example, [here](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/how-to-securely-empty-trash-in-os-x-el-capitan/) is random example where `srm` is used for securely emptying the trash bin. Notice that the example is for El Capitan, so `srm` disappeared in mac os Sierra (or at least, this appears to be the case).

Comment: The reason it was removed is that it's not secure. Why not use erase free space instead, or use FileVault?

Comment: The Mac Security Blog you mentioned says, "When OS X saves a copy of a file, it doesn't write that file to the same part of the disk. In layman's terms, what this means is that while you may be able to securely delete a file or folder, you cannot be certain that other copies of that file are not recoverable. As such, securely emptying the Trash is not reliable. While many Mac users miss this option, Apple felt it's better to be safe and not offer it if the feature isn't 100% reliable." See [CVE-2015-5901](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-5901).

Answer (score 12):

You can use `rm -P`

```
     -P          Overwrite regular files before deleting them.  Files are overwritten three times, first with the byte pattern 0xff, then 0x00, and then 0xff again, before they are deleted.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) and ...
2. Find ports: [srm](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=srm)
3. Terminal: `sudo port install srm`

Answer (score 1):

Apple removed `srm` because they felt it didn't work well enough and because using it on a SSD decreases the overall life of the drive. If you really want to use it you can download the [source](http://srm.sourceforge.net/), unzip it, and then compile it yourself.

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Comment: Have you got any sources backing up these claims why Apple removed `srm`?

Comment: @idmean "With an SSD drive, Secure Erase and Erasing Free Space are not available in Disk Utility. These options are not needed for an SSD drive because a standard erase makes it difficult to recover data from an SSD." https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201949

Comment: This no longer works; the `srm` formulae has been removed. There's a 3rd party [tap for it here](https://github.com/khell/homebrew-srm); install with `brew install khell/homebrew-srm/srm` then `srm secrets.txt`, etc. 
Better to not though.. see this [related question](https://superuser.com/a/1208987/160743).

Comment: Removed the section on installing from Homebrew.